# possible invalidoperationexception correct way to handle it

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I'm confused as to the best way to try and deal with possible InvalidOperationException.

In my code, I get a blue line under `(decimal)data.CurrencyExchangeRate` so changing the code to:

`data.CurrencyExchangeRate.GetValueOrDefault()` removes the blue line.

As the data is from a database and the column is a decimal, it will never be null.

So is `GetValueOrDefault` the best way to deal with the possible error?

I'm just not sure how best to handle it.

Thanks

Comment: Is data.CurrencyExchangeRate defined as a `decimal?` if so how. If this is Linq2Sql/Linq2Entities have you tried setting the not null option in the designer?

Comment: What data type is the `CurrencyExchangeRate` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CurrencyExchangeRate` is a nullable decimal, the `GetValueOrDefault` extension method is your safest bet - *if* you want to use a default of zero when the value is null.

For other default values, such as 1, use something like this:

```
decimal val = data.CurrencyExchangeRate.HasValue 
    ? data.CurrencyExchangeRate.Value
    : 1M;
```

The only exceptions you'll catch from `GetValueOrDefault` will be from the system such as OutOfMemoryExceptions etc. So it's unlikely you'll get an error here.

Comment: Hi Greg84, thanks, so the way I have done it and the example you have shown would both work.

Comment: Correct. You can use either your way or my way. Although you only need to use my way if you need a different default to that of the nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

You should still use a `try/catch`.  Never assume that the data from the database is always valid.  For example, what if I changed the datatype in the database to be a `VARCHAR` and added a `null` value, your application would crash.  Therefore it makes sense to handle the exception.

```
try {
    var value = data.CurrencyExchangeRate.GetValueOrDefault();
} catch (InvalidOperationException e) {
   // Log the exception
}
```

Comment: If you changed the datatype to varchar then the likelyhood is that the ORM would break before you even got that far.

Comment: Hi Darren, I have wrapped the code in a try catch block, sorry should have added that. I'm just confused on the best way to deal with this problem